# How to set language selector button to be above search icon list in header area on Shopify Dawn theme?

Tags: html, css, header, shopify

Hi guys I am not a coder I am trying to patch things together as I find them online, but I can't seem to find a way to do this, I want to move the google translate selector to above the list of search icons located on the top right side of the header area when in desktop and tablet mode it looks ok-ish on mobile now, you can see it on the site now here: https://convomediagroup.com

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47ZvG.jpg) what it looks like now on desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYLls.jpg) what mobile looks like

This is the css code I have right now for the google translate selector

```
/* Fab google translate button CSS Code */
.fab-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0.5rem;
  right: 1rem;
}
```

but I am not sure if CSS is the way to do it, maybe there is a better way to do this in the header code?  I don't know what to do... can someone show me where to move the google translate code, to have it show above the list of icons on the top right header area?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use absolute positioning to achieve this. We have to account for padding sizes, therefore we use `right: 1.5rem` on mobile and `right: 5rem` on desktop.

```
header.header--has-menu {
  position: relative;
}

.fab-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.5rem;
  top: 2rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 990px) {
  .fab-wrapper {
    right: 5rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi this works, but just one small thing, on the mobile now when I scroll down the page because the header would get smaller so the translator bar is covering up a little bit of the cart icon area, how would you get around this?

Comment: NVM I just turn that affect off on the header so it won't change it's size when you scroll down, but if you do have a solution for that I am down to changing it back, I think the animation for the header to shrink is with the logo shrink down to 70% or so, maybe we can make the selector shrink too?

Comment: ok I changed to this, should we make one for tablet too?

header.header--has-menu {
  position: relative;
}

.fab-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.025rem;
  top: 1.5rem;
  transform: scale(0.7);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 990px) {
  .fab-wrapper {
    right: 5rem;
    top: 2.5rem;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

Comment: hey Steffen, you know what I tested this on different phones and they could look somewhat different on each screen size, what if we do this, can we set this so that it is always aligned to the edge of the cart icon? no matter what the screen size is?